# Error updating foreign keys in MYSQL database where wrong option data from select boxes is used to update foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to php and I am trying to update a table in my MYSQL PHP database named mineraltable. I need to update foreign keys LocationID, ItemTypeID, ImageID and DonatorID.

These foreign keys link to the primary keys in the sourcelocationtable, itemtypetable, imagetable and donatortable respectively.

I have a form with 5 dropdown select boxes where the actual data values like site,Region,Country and continent are shown but when the user selects a location then the locationID (primary key of the sourcelocationtable) is recorded in a option data. This is the value I want inserted into the mineraltable as the foreign key linking to the sourcelocationtable. My overall php code for this file is below:

```
  <?php 


       $debugMode = true;

       $dbhost = 'localhost';
       $dbuser = 'root';
       $dbpass = '';
       $dbname = 'rockandmineraldb';
       $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

       if(! $conn ) {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }

       echo 'Connected successfully';


       $sql = 'SELECT LocationID,Site,Region,Country,Continent FROM sourcelocationtable';
       mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
       $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

       if(! $retval ) {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
       }

    $SiteOptionData="";
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
             $LocationID = $row['LocationID']; 
             $Site = $row['Site'];
             $Region = $row['Region'];
             $Country = $row['Country'];
             $Continent = $row['Continent'];

           $SiteOptionData .= "<option value-\"$LocationID\">$Site $Region $Country $Continent</option>";

    }




       $sql = 'SELECT DonatorID,DonatorFN,DonatorLN FROM donatortable';
       mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
       $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

       if(! $retval ) {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
       }

    $DonatorOptionData="";
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
             $DonatorID = $row['DonatorID']; 
             $DonatorFN = $row['DonatorFN'];
             $DonatorLN = $row['DonatorLN'];


           $DonatorOptionData .= "<option value-\"$DonatorID\">$DonatorFN $DonatorLN</option>";

    }


       $sql = 'SELECT ItemTypeID,ItemType FROM itemtypetable';
       mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
       $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

       if(! $retval ) {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
       }

    $ItemTypeOptionData="";
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
             $ItemTypeID = $row['ItemTypeID']; 
             $ItemType = $row['ItemType'];



           $ItemTypeOptionData .= "<option value-\"$ItemTypeID\">$ItemType</option>";

    }

       $sql = 'SELECT ImageID,Image FROM imagetable';
       mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
       $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

       if(! $retval ) {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
       }

    $ImageOptionData="";
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
             $ImageID = $row['ImageID']; 
             $Image = $row['Image'];

           $ImageOptionData .= "<option value-\"$ImageID\">$Image</option>";

    }

     $sql = 'SELECT ItemID,TrayBoxNo,ItemInBox,Name FROM mineraltable';
       mysql_select_db('rockandmineraldb');
       $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

       if(! $retval ) {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
       }

    $ItemOptionData="";
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
             $ItemID = $row['ItemID']; 
             $TrayBoxNo = $row['TrayBoxNo'];
             $ItemInBox = $row['ItemInBox'];
             $Name = $row['Name'];



           $ItemOptionData .= "<option value-\"$ItemID\">$TrayBoxNo,$ItemInBox,$Name</option>";

    }
       mysql_free_result($retval);
       echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

     if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

    if(isset($_POST['Item'])){ $ItemID== $_POST['Item']; } 
    if(isset($_POST['Location'])){ $LocationID = $_POST['Location']; } 
    if(isset($_POST['ItemType'])){ $ItemTypeID = $_POST['ItemType']; } 
    if(isset($_POST['Image'])){ $ImageID = $_POST['Image']; } 
    if(isset($_POST['Donator'])){ $DonatorID = $_POST['Donator']; } 




    $sql = "UPDATE `mineraltable` SET `LocationID`='$LocationID', `ItemTypeID`='$ItemTypeID', `ImageID`='$ImageID', `DonatorID`='$DonatorID' WHERE `ItemID`='$ItemID'";


                if(! $retval ) {
                   die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                echo "Updated data successfully\n";

                mysql_close($conn);

         die($sql);


     }
    ?>

      <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <table>
     <tr>
                        <td>Select Site</td>
                        <td>
                            <select size="10" name="Location" multiple="multiple" id="Location">


                                <?php echo $SiteOptionData; ?>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

        <br>


                    <tr>
        <td>Select Donator</td>
                        <td>
                            <select size="10" name="Donator" multiple="multiple" id="Donator">


                                <?php echo $DonatorOptionData; ?>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

    <br>

                    <tr>
        <td>Select ItemType</td>
                        <td>
                            <select size="10" name="ItemType" multiple="multiple" id="ItemType">


                                <?php echo $ItemTypeOptionData; ?>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

    <br>

                    <tr>
        <td>Select Image</td>
                        <td>


                            <select size="10" name="Image" multiple="multiple" id="Image">


                            <?php echo $ImageOptionData; ?> 

                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

        <td>Select Item</td>
                        <td>
                            <select size="10" name="Item" multiple="multiple" id="Item">


                                <?php echo $ItemOptionData; ?>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


    </table>

          <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="update">

        </form>
```

I have a php UPDATE statement to update the database with php variables selected from SELECT boxes. See below:

```
 if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

if(isset($_POST['Item'])){ $ItemID== $_POST['Item']; } 
if(isset($_POST['Location'])){ $LocationID = $_POST['Location']; } 
if(isset($_POST['ItemType'])){ $ItemTypeID = $_POST['ItemType']; } 
if(isset($_POST['Image'])){ $ImageID = $_POST['Image']; } 
if(isset($_POST['Donator'])){ $DonatorID = $_POST['Donator']; } 




$sql = "UPDATE `mineraltable` SET `LocationID`='$LocationID', `ItemTypeID`='$ItemTypeID', `ImageID`='$ImageID', `DonatorID`='$DonatorID' WHERE `ItemID`='$ItemID'";


            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";

            mysql_close($conn);

     die($sql);


 }
?>
```

But when I run this code in the web browser I get the success message

> "Updated data successfully UPDATE `mineraltable` SET
>   `LocationID`='Golden Bay Nelson New Zealand Australasia',
>   `ItemTypeID`='Mineral', `ImageID`='C:\xampp\htdocs\Images\Photo
>   composites-High Def\Box 2 checked19-01-2013.jpg', `DonatorID`='James
>   Smith' WHERE `ItemID`='373'"

So the values being inserted into the database are not the primary key ID numbers in the select box option data that are supposed to be stored but the actual word data values. Can someone please tell me why the IDs in the select boxes are not being stored and handed to the UPDATE statement to be used to update the mineraltable?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have changed the - to a = and it now sends the ID to the browser rather than the word value which I have checked by echoing out the query. I also get the success message "Updated data successfully" But when I check the mineraltable in phpMyAdmin I find that the data in the LocationID, ImageID, ItemTypeID, and DonatorID fields is still NULL. Is there still a error in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are HTML coding problem like `<option value-`, it will be `<option value=`

Change your coding from

```
$SiteOptionData .= "<option value-\"$LocationID\">$Site $Region $Country $Continent</option>";

 $DonatorOptionData .= "<option value-\"$DonatorID\">$DonatorFN $DonatorLN</option>";

$ItemTypeOptionData .= "<option value-\"$ItemTypeID\">$ItemType</option>";

$ImageOptionData .= "<option value-\"$ImageID\">$Image</option>";

$ItemOptionData .= "<option value-\"$ItemID\">$TrayBoxNo,$ItemInBox,$Name</option>";
```

To

```
$SiteOptionData .= "<option value=\"$LocationID\">$Site $Region $Country $Continent</option>";

 $DonatorOptionData .= "<option value=\"$DonatorID\">$DonatorFN $DonatorLN</option>";

$ItemTypeOptionData .= "<option value=\"$ItemTypeID\">$ItemType</option>";

$ImageOptionData .= "<option value=\"$ImageID\">$Image</option>";

$ItemOptionData .= "<option value=\"$ItemID\">$TrayBoxNo,$ItemInBox,$Name</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your HTML.  You have:

```
$SiteOptionData .= "<option value-\"$LocationID\">
```

But you need a = after value, not -:

```
$SiteOptionData .= "<option value=\"$LocationID\">
```

That will get the browser to properly send the ID.